# Calculating covariant derivative in Null Tetrad

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $m_a := \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\nabla_a \theta + i \sin \theta \nabla_a \phi)$ with $\eta_{ab}m^a\bar{m}^b=1$ and the metric
be given by $s_{ab} = m_{(a}\bar{m}_{b)}$. For a $1$-form $v_a$ with $v_am^a = f$ it is claimed that:
$$m^a(\hat\nabla_a m^b)v_b =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cot (\theta) f $$

With $\nabla$ C.D. on $\eta$ and $\hat\nabla$ C.D. on $s$.
Why does this hold? How to calculate this?

Comment: Ah actually it is all clear now. The calculation is just tedious. But in the end I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Calculating the Christoffel Symbols wrt to the Levi-Civita connection of the 2-sphere metric we have:

$$\Gamma^\theta\,_{\phi \phi} = -\sin \theta cos \theta$$
and
$$\Gamma^\phi\,_{\phi \theta} = \Gamma^\phi\,_{\theta\phi}= \cot \theta$$

The others are 0. Therefore we get

$$ m^\phi (\hat \nabla_\phi m^\phi) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cot (\theta)\, m^\phi$$
and
$$ m^\phi (\hat \nabla_\phi m^\theta) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cot(\theta)\, m^\theta$$